# How do I get rid of side bar in MacOS Texmaker pdf viewer window?

Tags: pdf, texmaker, macos

I'm trying to use the built-in pdf viewer in Texmaker on MacOS, but on a separate window from the tex editor. However, there's this large empty space on the left of the pdf viewer window that is intended for either the document structure navigation or the pages navigation. I can "hide" either of these navigation options, but I don't seem to be able to hide the empty space itself, nor am I ablle to reduce its width.
[image: Screenshot of problem here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to "view" tab and then checkmark the "pages" icon. Now by placing your mouse curser at the edge of empty space you can change its size or by clicking on the cross icon at the top of the free space you can close it.

Comment: This works, thank you!