# TexMaker's internal pdf viewer is too narrow

Tags: texmaker

I just downloaded the latest version of TeXMaker for Mac. The internal pdf viewer, which I set up to open in a separate window, has a blank space to the left of the actual file displayed. This space keeps about 20% of the screen. There is no separator to move to reduce the size of the space. Any ideas on how to get rid of this empty useless space?

Comment: You might want to try out texstudio instead. It has more or less the same features as texmaker and then some. One interesting feature is a button to pop out the PDF viewer in a separate window (and you can pop it back in by a click of a button).

Comment: There's not much you can do for those screen space consuming blank sections (I had tried to get rid of them too but couldn't)

Comment: I don't have that editor but isn't this the same as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586681/how-do-i-get-rid-of-side-bar-in-macos-texmaker-pdf-viewer-window?rq=1

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you a lot for this link!

Comment: don't thank me, the site added it automatically to the "Related links" list in the right hand sidebar, based on the words in your question. I just copied it from there:-)